# Datos dinámicos base de datos

Tags: android, php, json, mysql

Tengo una base de datos en mysql que administro con php admin, los datos son consultados por una aplicacion en android a través de PHP y JSON, todo hasta aquí esta perfecto, lo que quiero es que cada vez que realice una modificación en phpadmin de la base de datos como actualizar, insertar eliminar registros, esto se vea reflejado en tiempo real o de forma instantánea en la app sin necesidad de tener que cerrar y abrir la app para que esto ocurra.. cual quier sugerencia, comentario se lo agradecere mucho, saludos y gracias por su atencion.

Aquí la clase:

```
  public class VerA extends ActionBarActivity {

  String myJSON;

  private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombre";
private static final String TAG_ADD ="telefono";
private Handler mHandler;
private int mInterval = 8000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later


JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();
    getData();



}

// METODO QUE MUESTRA LA LISTA O LA MATRIZ
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                VerA.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


///METODO QUE EXTRAE LOS DATOS DE EL JASON PHP
public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.108/selectAllJSON.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}


  /// METODO PARA HACER QUE SE EJECUTE LA CONSULTA A LA BD CADA 8 SEGUNDOS, EL QUE NO FUNCIONA 
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getData();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
    }
};
void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run();
}
}
```

Ultima modificacion al codigo:

```
 public class VerA extends ActionBarActivity {

String myJSON;

private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombre";
private static final String TAG_ADD ="telefono";
Handler handler = new Handler();


JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    getData();



}



 // METODO QUE MUESTRA LA LISTA O LA MATRIZ
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                VerA.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


  ///METODO QUE EXTRAE LOS DATOS DE EL JASON PHP
public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tuescuelanoticias.x10.mx/selectAllJSON.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}


 ///LOS METODOS SIGUIENTES MUESTRAN LA OPCION DE MENU Y CONFIGRUACIO
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
 ///DISQUE PARA QUE SE REFRESQUE CADA 8 SEGUNDOS
 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
    showList();
        // Do some updates
        handler.postDelayed(this, 8000);

  }
  };


  }
```

al ejecutarlo en la terminal o en mi movil , cada 8 segundos se van repitiendo los datos, pero si modifico desde php admin la base de datos, no se refelja en la app

Comment: Hola @user3707302 nos puedes indicar cual dónde o cuál es el problema? No está claro cual es la pregunta.

Comment: Supuestamente desde tu app deberías volver a consultar el servicio (hecho en PHP o lo que fuese) para volver a obtener la información con los datos actualizados. No entiendo cuál es el problema.

Comment: hola@CarlosMuñoz y @Luiggi Mendoza, gracias por responder, exacto, es lo que intento hacer, volver a consultar el servicio en PHP de forma automática cada 8 segundos, de tal forma que si modifico las tablas de la  base de dato usando phpadmin, en la app se vea la modificación de forma instantánea, hasta el momento aparentemente la app muestra los datos en una lista infinita repitiendolos, y si desde el phpadmin modifico esto no se refleja en la app

Comment: Lo que requieres es implementar notificaciones push. Esto requiere hacer un desarrollo extra en php (o el lenguaje que estimes conveniente) que realice el cambio en la DB y al finalizar el cambio, envíe una notificación push al dispositivo avisando que hay información nueva, en ese momento el dispositivo consume nuevamente tu base de datos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta que se trata de una aplicación Android, la estrategia de notificar al aplicativo Android cuando se ha producido un cambio en la data de tu backend para luego disparar una operación de actualización de los datos en la BD de tu equipo es lo más recomendable.

Te dejo una pequeña explicación gráfica. Espero te ayude.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Usar [`retrofit`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) como biblioteca para hacer peticiones REST
2. Cada vez que hagas un `insert`, un `delete`, un `update`, debes agregar o eliminarla de tu `adapter`, y usar el metodo `notifyDataSetChanged()`, para que en automatico se actualice la `listview`
3. Programa usando el paradigma POO para que tu código sea mantenible y funcional.

Comment: gracias pro sus  respuestas y comentarios César y ClarkXP @honestamente soy nuevo en Poo y en andorid, apenas me defiendo en php,en si la app que pretendo solo es una especie de visualizador de avisos, he leído sobre notificaciones push y el GCM, y lo que tengo entendido es que el funcionamiento seria similar ya que los servicios google constantemente estarían verificando la base de datos, por lo tanto pensé en hacerlo mas independiente de los servicios google, y que la propia app cada X segundos verifique la base de datos

Comment: en php seria algo muy fácil ya que solamente haria una consulta directa y con javscript que la pagina se actualice cada X segundos entonces el escript de php se ejecuta nuevamente mostrando nuevamente los datos y si yo modifico en php admins los datos se reflejan, es mas o menos lo que quisiera que se pudiera hacer de alguna forma....

Comment: el siguiente link es de un caso similar al mio, pero no logro implementar el código: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045217/android-json-auto-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Una solución bastante sencilla sería aplicar a tus registros una "versión". Consistiría en añadir a cada tabla de tu BDD que quisieras comprobar una nueva columna numérica que incrementara su valor con cada insert/update de la tabla a observar. Esto se controlaría mediante un trigger que actuara con update o insert. Según tus necesidades es posible que no se necesitara hacer en cada tabla, si no crear una nueva tabla con un único registro que fuera ese número de "versión".

Luego, desde cada dispositivo, en la comprobación que hiciera cada 8 segundos se podría comparar la última versión de esa tabla/BDD que tuviera guardada el dispositivo (SQLite, shared preferences, etc.), con el último valor del campo "versión". Si ésta fuera diferente, debería actualizar los datos.

Es una solución poco ortodoxa pero simple, en mi opinión, y que no requeriría utilizar API's o servicios "externos". De hecho, la apliqué para un proyecto y funciona perfectamente.